# Adobe Flash Setting Pop-up

Tags: flash, adobe, popup

Is there any way to remove/modify the Flash Media Setting pop-up window?

When prompted to use a flash-based player, I am prompted with the Adobe Settings/Permissions window. I would like to modifiy the UI of this window, if possible.

If I cannot modify the look of the window, is there any way to regulate when the window pops up or when that permission is granted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, for security reasons the Flash Player Settings panels are not accessible to developers, therefore you cannot modify or remove any of them.

Things you cannot control in Flash Player Settings panel:

- The UI from any component within the settings panels
- There are no Events being dispatched (neither by components or by the panel itself)
- You cannot force a panel to close
- There's no way to know if a panel is open or closed (note that the user can use the flash menu to open the settings panel)

The only thing you can control is which panel should be open, after that it's all up to the user.

To open a Security Panel (i.e. the Camera panel):

```
Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);
```

For more security panels check the [SecurityPanel documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/SecurityPanel.html).